# English BIOS is now Chinese / English

Tags: bios, motherboard, language

My motherboard (MSI B450 Tomahawk MAX (MS-7C02) (AM4)), bought almost 3 years ago from a reputable seller, has a funny way of speaking English:

[image: MSI click bios 5 screenshot]

I do recall it used to be full English, about a year ago. Not the weird mix of Chinese / English it is now. However, the setting in the top right states the language is English.

The motherboard hasn't been flashed since July '19 or so and last time I checked the BIOS (new RAM) was over a year ago. It was still in proper English back then. Yet, meanwhile, somehow, the language changed.

How did that happen and how do I put it back to proper English?

Answer (score 0):

While I do not know what caused it and it's not a fix by a longshot, I did figure out a workaround. Use a different language. Like German:

[image: Same image, in German-English]

Most of the words are still in English anyway and this language doesn't seem affected.